# how to get all the types of one index by using Nest(Elasticsearch) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

if use original api /_mapping, I can get all he information of all types for each index.

but when I use Nest, I can not see the way to do the same thing like /_mapping does. Nest has getMapping, but you must give a mapped type(object).

and I still not find any way to pass the /_mapping web api through Nest.

How to get the list of types of each indexes in Nest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found way to do this with Nest.

Nest actually provider a `ElasticSearchClient` within the object itself. the field call `Raw` actually provide all the API from `ElasticSearchClient`. and all the APIs mapped to the ElasticSearch REST web api, and give the JSON result directly.

to answer this question. the following code can be used:

```
var nestClient = new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")));
var Response = nestClient.Raw.IndicesGetMapping();
var JSONResult=Response.Result;
```

JSONResult is String. Later on, this can be parsed by `JObject.Parse(JSONResult);` to get the JObject and processed further  in C#.

**This answer is only working for NEST 0.12, NEST 1.0 change the API completely**